# Scheduling Task in iOS Device

Tags: ios, background, location, eventkit

Is there any way to schedule a task on iOS? I want to schedule location tracking start/stop event. Let's say start Location tracking at 9:00 AM Daily & Stop it 6:00 PM Daily. Please suggest a solution. Does the event kit help me with this?

Comment: No, there is no specific time scheduling in iOS.

Comment: Why can't you use the Silent Notification?

Comment: Suggest rethink what functions you want. User may not use your app the whole day and hence no need to stop it at a specific time each day.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, look at following: [Scheduling and Handling Local Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html)

You can use Notification Trigger, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Notification Trigger](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SupportingNotificationsinYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH4-SW26) and [CLLocationManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager) and as per your requirement you can schedule option like [this](https://transistorsoft.github.io/cordova-background-geolocation-lt/interfaces/_cordova_background_geolocation_lt_.config.html#schedule)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

iOS have't any specific scheduling for location tracking.
You can make notification with deep link (or special payload) and user open application and start or stop tracking.

Links who can help -
[Basic about usernotifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/)
[Scheduling a notification locally from your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/scheduling_a_notification_locally_from_your_app)
[About deep link](https://clevertap.com/blog/deep-linking/)

Also you can't use for this issue - silent push notification or VoIP push notification, beacuse it contrary to Apple policy.
**Silent push** - can't wake up terminated application, and have some frequency limit.
[developer.apple.com/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app)

> The system treats background notifications as low-priority: you can
>   use them to refresh your app’s content, but the system doesn’t
>   guarantee their delivery. In addition, the system may throttle the
>   delivery of background notifications if the total number becomes
>   excessive. The number of background notifications allowed by the
>   system depends on current conditions, but don’t try to send more than
>   two or three per hour.

**VoIP push** - should using only for VoIP call, if you don't open CallKit after VoIP, iOS can ban VoIP notification for your app.
[developer.apple.com/pushkit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit/pkpushregistrydelegate/2875784-pushregistry)

> On iOS 13.0 and later, if you fail to report a call to CallKit, the
>   system will terminate your app. Repeatedly failing to report calls may
>   cause the system to stop delivering any more VoIP push notifications
>   to your app. If you want to initiate a VoIP call without using
>   CallKit, register for push notifications using the UserNotifications
>   framework instead of PushKit. For more information, see
>   UserNotifications.